# why "missing right parenthesis" error?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Why does the query produce this error?

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

```
select * from
(
  (select * from dual) alias1,

  (select * from dual) alias2
)
```

I get an error on 10g and 11g

Comment: just remove the outer ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect SQL syntax. Remove outer pair of parenthesis, like this:

```
select * from 
(select * from dual) alias1, 
(select * from dual) alias2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are balanced, but the parser is confused, and in its confusion, it generated a sub-optimal error message.

You could write something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM Dual) Alias1
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM Dual) Alias2 ON 1 = 1;
```